# Eclipse MARS: MercurialEclipse install reports "Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

The exact error message is...

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.


Plugin: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite 1.0.500.v20150423-1455
Message: Error reading update site http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable.
```

I get the same error message on both version 2.1 and 1.8 via the Eclipse MarketPlace.

[image: Error]

If I install another plugin like "EMMA", that works fine.

If I select "Help" > "Check for updates", I get the same error message.

Can anyone suggest a fix/workaround ?

NOTES:

Installing via the update URL works (SNAPSHOT ONLY, not RELEASE)

http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/snapshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just facing the same issue.

What worked for me was that i needed to close the address to work

http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable/

You need the trailing / at the end of your update site.

Hope this works for you as well.

Comment: With mars 4.5.0 I need a trailing / and a dot 
i.e
http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable/.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help -> Install New Software -> Add and copy this "http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable/." to the location and then click add and you will see the packages to install

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this with Eclipse 4.4.2 -- which works well -- and Eclipse 4.5.0 -- which throws the aforementioned error. Adding a trailing slash does not help me at all.

This looks like a typical UTF BOM issue in the repository, but it seems to be caused by a change in behaviour between `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite/1.0.400.v20131211-1531` and `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite/1.0.500.v20150423-1455`

That said, there is a reason why `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite` plug-in is called "Legacy Update Site Support", and that's because old site.xml-based update sites have been deprecated since Eclipse 3.6 release in 2010. Why MercurialEclipse plug-in does not publish a p2 update site is beyond me.

UPDATE 2015-09-22: I've just downloaded a fresh Eclipse SDK 4.5.0 and don't see this error any longer.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with Eclipse 4.5.0 that I installed on 14-09-2015 (mkalkov stated that a 4.5.0 downloaded on the 22nd didn't have this problem). Adding a trailing slash didn't fix it. I tried using snapshots and no errors popped up:

http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/snapshots/

It may not be perfect since it's not stable, but it's easier then reinstalling Eclipse. Which I recommend you do if you have the time.